# GraphQL query parameter syntax for passing variables

Tags: meteor, graphql

So I'm trying to access a specific document in my database via GraphQL query inside my Meteor app. I parse the document ID from my url, and I'm trying to create a gql query to get that document, however my query returns undefined because the parameter for the query is undefined. I'm not sure where I have something wrong since I'm still very new to GraphQL.

Query

```
    const contactId = instance.getContactId();
    const CONTACT_QUERY = gql`
        query contact {
            contact(_id: "${contactId}") {
                _id
                name
                customerId
                phone
                email
                position
                decisionMaker
            }
        }
    `;
```

Schema

```
type Contact {
    _id: String!
    name: String!
    customerId: String
    phone: String
    email: String
    position: String
    decisionMaker: String
}

type Query {
    contacts: [Contact]
    contact(_id: String!): Contact
}
```

Resolver

```
import { Contacts } from './contacts.js';

export default {
  Query: { 
    contacts() {
        return Contacts.find({}).fetch();
    },
    contact(contactId) {
        console.log(contactId);
        return Contacts.findOne({_id: contactId});
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: `variables` are not passed this way - read docs and use `query tester` `/graphiql`

Answer (score 0):

Doing a GraphQL query does not load documents into minimongo, so your client-side `Meteor.Collection`s will be empty. Usually people choose to either use Meteor's livedata system (publications, subscriptions, Collections, and Methods) or Apollo (Queries and Mutations). If you want to do the latter, follow Apollo's docs for how to execute `CONTACT_QUERY` and access the results.

Comment: I'm using Apollo and the blaze-apollo package to handle the data. On my Blaze template is where I'm constructing the query based on the ID parameter, and using the blaze-apollo package to run the query.

    const { contacts } = Template.instance().gqlQuery({ query: 
    CONTACTS_QUERY, }).get();

The issue is that it returns undefined and I'm not sure how to construct my query properly when I have the ID of the document I want.

Comment: Check out this section and the linked `watchQuery` options, including `variables`: https://github.com/Swydo/blaze-apollo#graphql-queries